# GUI library alternative to Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter has released a GUI framework/library called Bootstrap.

Twitter Bootstrap is good quality, nice-looking, and fully-formed form/layout declaration, but can anyone recommend some similar framework/library other than Twitter Bootstrap?

Some might suggest jQueryUI, but I think jQueryUI's css/graphic is not good enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) is close but doesn't have as many features (not even close).

Comment: .. is close ... not even close. Hmm. :)

Comment: Bootstrap has added a lot of cruft in 2 years. Today that statement is even more true. :)

Answer (score 46):

I currently see two great alternatives for `twitter bootstrap`, they are:

- [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/)
- [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/)

Both of them are complete enough and also support many browsers. Give them a try :)

Comment: +1, especially for the foundation link, very impressive!

Comment: +1, especially for HTML Kickstart, impressive than Zurb Foundation :-)

Answer (score 11):

Here is another:
http://www.99lime.com/elements/ ( http://github.com/joshuagatcke/HTML-KickStart )

HTML KickStart is an ultra–lean set of HTML5, CSS, and jQuery (javascript) files, layouts, and elements designed to give you a headstart and save you 10's of hours on your next web project.

Comment: HTML KickStart is a worthy alternative to Bootstrap. Very impressive.

Answer (score 4):

Took the words out my mouth with Foundation and Kickstart. Also, you may want to check out [HTML5 Boilerplate Redux](http://r3versin.com/redux/) and/or the original Boilerplate. I've done extensive research in templates, alas, these are the best when it comes to plug-and-play.

However, if it's mobile-up you want, there's Skeleton (as mentioned earlier in thread - I love it), foneFrame (If you do it right, it looks awesome + it loads very fast)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some other CSS frameworks that you can try:

- [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)
- [Bluepring CSS Framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)
- [frameless grid](http://framelessgrid.com/)
- [the square grid](http://thesquaregrid.com)

Comment: Bulma.io is a good alternative too

Answer (score 3):

And more frameworks:

- Less Framework : http://lessframework.com/
- YAML CSS Framework : http://www.yaml.de/

Comment: Yaml it's a nice bootstrap alternative, I think it is the most similar alternative to bootstrap, indeed.